# Loading inline SVG in vuejs via prop into a component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, svg, webpack, inline

I am trying to load an inline svg into my component.

App.vue

template

```
<vue-anime :url="'planetiaermma.svg'" />
```

anime.vue

```
  <div>
    <div v-html="this.loadSVG()"></div>
    <img :src="this.svgfile()" alt />
  </div>
```

```
  props: ["url"],

  methods: {
    svgfile() {
      var img = this.getImgUrl(this.url);
      return img;
    },
    getImgUrl(pic) {
      return require("../assets/" + pic);
    },

    loadSVG() {
      var img = this.getImgUrl(this.url);
      var svgraw;
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        fetch(img)
          .then(res => res.text())
          .then(svg => {
            svgraw = svg;
          });
      });
      return svgraw;
    },
    mounted() {
      this.loadSVG();
    }
  }
};
```

firing `svgfile()` into a `:src` works

firing `loadSVG()` should load it inline, does not seem to however, even though the `return svgraw;` is in a string of html/xml.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use something like [`vue-inline-svg`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-inline-svg) for this:

```sh
npm install vue-inline-svg
```

and register the component globally in your `main.js` file:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import InlineSvg from 'vue-inline-svg';

Vue.component('inline-svg', InlineSvg);

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

After that you can use the component anywhere inside your templates

> Note: if you use vue-loader assets or vue-cli, then paths like '../assets/my.svg' will not be handled by file-loader automatically like vue-cli do for  tag, so you will need to use it with require:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <inline-svg :src="require(`../assets/${url}`)" />
 <!-- You also can specify some props -->
 <!-- width="150" -->
 <!-- height="150" -->
 <!-- :fill="false" -->
  </div>
</template>
```

and get rid of that messy code.

Comment: Cool thanks! I was looking for a loader like this. Not sure how i missed this one.
I did look at the source code of it, it uses the same idea than what i did by loading the data via a get request. seems to be the only way to actually load it inline.

Comment: I was looking at this [one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-svg-inline-loader) at first, but it has a [problem](https://github.com/oliverfindl/vue-svg-inline-loader/issues/2#issuecomment-400548461) with vue bindings, because this loader only parses static files and it does not handle vue logic at that point.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you getting from `getImgUrl()` but could you try this?

```
mounted() {
   this.$nextTick(() => {
    this.loadSVG();
   });
}
```

You might also try this to be sure it's not from missing value:

```
<img v-if="svgURL" :src="svgURL" alt />


data() {
  return {
    svgURL: null
  }
}

mounted() {
  loadSVG() {
    this.svgURL = 'YOUR VALUE'
  }
}
```

Please avoid using `this` inside the template.

Comment: I kept getting `undefined` for some reason. But I did manage to get it to work. My problem was also that `mounted` ended up in the method brackets.

Answer (score 0):

App.vue

```
<vue-anime :url="'planet.svg'" />
```

anime.vue component

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-html="mysvgfile"></div>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
export default {
  props: ["url"],

  data() {
    return {
      mysvgfile: ""
    };
  },

  methods: {
    svgfile() {
      var img = this.getImgUrl(this.url);
      return img;
    },
    getImgUrl(pic) {
      return require("../assets/" + pic);
    },

    loadSVG() {
      var img = this.getImgUrl(this.url);
      var outer = this;
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        fetch(img)
          .then(res => res.text())
          .then(svg => {
            outer.mysvgfile = svg;
          });
      });
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.loadSVG();
  }
};
```